# Applying Inverse Function Theorem to Matrix Exponential

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> If $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of real $n \times n$ matrices, define $\text{Exp}:M(n, \mathbb{R}) \to M(n, \mathbb{R})$ by
> $$
> \text{Exp}(A) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}A^k.
> $$
> Show that there exists a neighborhood $\mathcal{O}$ of $0 \in M(n,\mathbb{R})$ and a neighborhood $U$ of the identity matrix $I \in M(n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\text{Exp}:\mathcal{O} \to U$ is one-to-one and onto.

I believe using inverse function theorem is the way to go here, but I am unsure how to apply it. I am able to prove $\text{Exp}(0) = I$ easily, but then I have to show that the function is $C^1$ and its derivative is nonzero at zero.

I'm not familiar with calculating derivatives of matrix functions like this. I would think it should be easy to show that $\frac{d}{dA}\text{Exp}(A) = \text{Exp}(A)$ from which the result would follow easily, but I'm getting stuck and a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Compute the directional derivative at $A=0$, i.e., the derivative of $\exp tA’$ with respect to $t$, evaluated at $t=0$.